# How to interpret airline PNR printouts

Tags: tickets, airlines, bookings

I have a following air itinerary/PNR printout. How do I decode this? What does each line and column signify?

> TK 693 V 14MAY 7 CAIIST HK1       3  0240 0550   32B E 0 M
>   SEE RTSVC
>
> 2  TK 661 V 14MAY 7 ISTTUN HK1       I  0830 0925   333 E 0 M
>   SEE RTSVC
>
> 3  TK 664 V 21MAY 7 TUNIST HK1       M  1700 2145   321 E 0 M
>   SEE RTSVC
>
> 4  TK 692 V 22MAY 1 ISTCAI HK1       I  0035 0145   32B E 0 M
>   SEE RTSVC

Answer (score 17):

In your PNR, there is 1 line for every leg of your trip, and in each line the details of this leg.

For 1st line:

- TK 693 = airline company + flight number
- V = Class
- 14MAY = date of departure
- 7 = day of week (here Sunday)
- CAIIST = airport codes of your itinerary (CAI = Cairo to IST = Istanbul)
- HK1 = hold confirmed - 1 person on booking
- 3 = departure terminal
- 0240 = time of departure (departure airport local time)
- 0550 = time of arrival (arrival airport local time)
- 32B = aircraft type (Airbus 321)
- E = Electronic ticket type
- 0 = number of stops
- M = meal code

Comment: And "RTSVC" means restricted service - typically can only be booked as part of an itinerary and not as a standalone flight.

Comment: HK1 - hold confirmed - 1 person on booking

Comment: +1. May be worthwhile to point out that time of arrival and departure are local to the arrival/departure airports.

Comment: @RedBaron Will add it